# Office365 Outlook still receive Emails but DNS/MX settings pointing to the another server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

we have around 10 `Office365` accounts (we are using those accounts explicit for `Outlook`). One of those account has been moved to another server (`Hostgator`) and all `MX, DNS` entries are successufuly updated to the right hosting (`Hostgator`).

Now, if somebody from rest of 9 `Office365` users send an email to this migrated mail, email goes in the `Office365` inbox, and if somebody from `gmail`, `yahoo` etc sends than it comes to new (right) inbox (`hostgator`)

How can I completley disable `office365` account to recieve emails only in hostgator inbox and why we are getting emails in `office365` if `DNS` and `mx` settings are pointing to another server?

Thank you

Comment: When did you change the DNS entries? Those can have an unpleasant delay if caches isn't cleared.

Comment: 14 days ago, and if I make mx/nslookup tests online, all settings are pointing to the new server, but still emails goes to the old office365 inbox (only in case that somebody send email from office365 account)

Comment: And if you do a 'nslookup' on your client computers, what does it say? Does it also point to the new server?